# Sometimes custom loading popup doesn't show

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, loading

In my application loading popup is shown every time when I call It. But some times It just doesn't show and it is same situation. Popup is a custom UserControl object made with WPF.

Popup is in **MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <Grid>          
        <Grid x:Name="Body" Height="768" Width="1024" Background="{StaticResource SCBPassiveColor}" />
        <src:InfoPane x:Name="InfoPaneMaster"  Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

In the Body of the main window application loads selected layout/view. Before new layout is loaded program calls :

```
LayoutCommands.DisplayInfoPane(msgLoginSuccess, ROPInfo.Info, null);
```

**implementation:**

```
public void DisplayInfoPane(string infoText, ROPInfo infoType, int? displayTime)
{
    StopTimer();
    SetTimer(displayTime ?? DefaultDisplayTime);
    PrepareInfoPane(infoText, infoType);
    colCloseIcon.Width = new GridLength(0);
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

The popup automatically  closes (sets visibility to collapsed) after default time.

Why sometimes this popup just doesn't show? Is this associated with rendering?

Comment: wild guess: if timer ends just after another popup opens, then its visibility doesn't have the time to be set to Visible.

Comment: I'll try your Idea. Often the simplest solution is the right one.